# Why must I focus out or press Enter once in two to continue?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem with my script.

When I change an input number by arrows to up or down value, it is supposed to calculate another value.
First time it's okay but then I must lose focus (by clicking out or pressing `Enter`) to calculate or I must wait several seconds...

This is my .js :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    calcul_prix();

    $("#largeur_conf").change(function(){
        calcul_prix();
    });

    $("#hauteur_conf").change(function(){
        calcul_prix();
    });

    $("#nb_rideaux_1").click(function(){
        calcul_prix();
    });

    $("#nb_rideaux_2").click(function(){
        calcul_prix();
    });    
});

function calcul_prix()
{
    verif_saisie();

    var largeur = parseInt(document.getElementById("largeur_conf").value);
    var hauteur = parseInt(document.getElementById("hauteur_conf").value);
    var nb_rideaux = parseInt(document.querySelector('input[name="nb_rideaux"]:checked').value);

    prix_confection = largeur * nb_rideaux;

    $('#prix_final').text(formatCurrency(prix_confection, currencyFormat, currencySign, currencyBlank));
}

function verif_saisie()
{
    var largeur = parseInt(document.getElementById("largeur_conf").value);
    var hauteur = parseInt(document.getElementById("hauteur_conf").value);

    if(largeur > 500 || largeur < 50) 
    {
        document.getElementById("largeur_conf").value = 50;
    }

    if(hauteur > 500 || hauteur < 50) 
    {
        document.getElementById("hauteur_conf").value = 50;
    }
}
```

Comment: Because `onchange` is triggered after the element is blurred. Use `oninput` event to detect real time changes.

Comment: Okay but how can I change ? `$("#largeur_conf").input(function(){` is not good ?

Comment: Hmm ... input event seems not to have a jQuery shortcut, use `on` method, `$('#largeur_conf').on('input', calcul_prix);`

Comment: Okay ! `oninput` is good but now I can't type number with keyboard in my input fields because `oninput` event is here

Comment: It [doesn't have anything to do with typing](https://jsfiddle.net/g8r44ouj/) to the input, your code fails somewhere else. Notice, that now you really have a real time validation, is the rest of the code created for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how the `change` event works. According [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change), the event is triggered for `input` elements of type text, ...

> ...When the element loses focus after its value was changed

Look into the [`input` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input) instead:

> The DOM input event is fired synchronously when the value of an `<input>`, `<select>`, or `<textarea>` element is changed

This event fires independent of whether the change happened via the keyboard, context menu, mouse (e.g. drag-drop) or other device.

There are also some other things you can improve in your code:

- Use jQuery syntax instead of `document.getElementById`
- Combine selectors into one
- Pass a function reference instead of wrapping one function call in an anonymous function
- Use the unary plus for conversion to number

Code:

```
$(function() {
    calcul_prix();
    $("#largeur_conf, #hauteur_conf").on('input', calcul_prix);
    $("#nb_rideaux_1, #nb_rideaux_2").click(calcul_prix);
});

function calcul_prix() {
    verif_saisie();
    var largeur = +$("#largeur_conf").val(),
        hauteur = +$("#hauteur_conf").val(),
        nb_rideaux = +$('input[name="nb_rideaux"]:checked').val();

    prix_confection = largeur * nb_rideaux;
    $('#prix_final').text(formatCurrency(prix_confection, currencyFormat, currencySign, currencyBlank));
}

function verif_saisie() {
    var largeur = +$("#largeur_conf").val(),
        hauteur = +$("#hauteur_conf").val();

    if (largeur > 500 || largeur < 50) {
        $("#largeur_conf").val(50);
    }

    if (hauteur > 500 || hauteur < 50) {
        $("#hauteur_conf").val(50);
    }
}
```

Be aware that you will not be able to enter a value below 50, as your code will set it back to 50 immediately now. It would be better if you would not set the value to 50 in that case, but just show an error message. That way the user can still enter a number starting with 1 digit.

Comment: Now, I can't type with the keyboard on my inputs number ?

Comment: That is because you set the value to 50 when you enter anything below 50. I would suggest not to do that, but to show an error message instead. That way the user can type the complete number one digit at a time.